# error al guardar datos en struct desde un JSON

Tags: json, swift, xcode, struct, alamofire

estoy intentando hacer un struct con el siguiente resultado de alamofire ( no es el completo, pero es el que me da error:

```
weather =     (
                {
            description = "clear sky";
            icon = 01d;
            id = 800;
            main = Clear;
        }
    );
```

En Xcode tengo lo siguiente:

```
struct NameWeatherResponse: Codable {
    ...
    var coord: Coord?
    var weather: Weather?
   ...
}

struct Weather: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var main, weatherDescription, icon: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, main
        case weatherDescription = "description"
        case icon
    }
}
```

y tambien he probado lo siguiente:

```
struct Weather: Codable {
    var id: Int?
    var main, description, icon: String?

    
}
```

Si comento en NameWeatherResponse la variable weather funciona todo correctamente, pero hay datos que me gustaria recuperar de aqui.

Alguien puede ayudarme? Muchas gracias :D

Comment: En el Json, el valor de icon es string? Puedes agregar el error?

Comment: De qué tipo es `Clear`? Esa estructura del Json no parece estar bien.

Answer (score 1):

Estas indicando que  main, weatherDescription e icon son de tipo String opcionales, pero en el Json solo indicas que solo "weatherDescription" es de tipo String, las variables "icon" y "main" no tienen las comillas que indican que ese tipo de dato es String.

Intenta usar esto:

```
description = "clear sky";
        icon = "01d";
        id = 800;
        main = "Clear";
```

Espero esto ayude.
Saludos!